# Open an authenticated image served by django from java using Apache http client

Tags: java, django, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I Am serving an authenticated image using django. The image is behind a view which require login, and in the end I have to check more things than just the authentication.
Because of a reason to complicated to explain here, I cannot use the real url to the image, but I Am serving it with a custom url leading to the authenticated view.

From java the image must be reachable, to save or display. For this part I use Apache httpclient.

In Apacahe I tried a lot of things (every example and combination of examples...) but can't seem to get it working.
For other parts of the webapp I use django-rest-framwork, which I succesfully connected to from java (and c and curl).

I use the login_reuired decorator in django, which makes the attempt to get to the url redirect to a login page first.

Trying the link and the login in a webviewer, I see the 200 code (OK) in the server console.
Trying the link with the httpclient, I get a 302 Found in the console.... (looking up 302, it means a redirect..)

this is what I do in django:

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^photolink/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'myapp.views.photolink',name='photolink'),
```

in views.py:

```
import mimetypes
import os

@login_required
def photolink(request, filename):
    # from the filename I get the image object, for this question not interesting
    # there is a good reason for this complicated way to reach a photo, but not the point here
    filename_photo = some_image_object.url
    base_filename=os.path.basename(filename_photo)
    # than this is the real path and filename to the photo:
    path_filename=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'photos',mac,base_filename)
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename_photot)[0]
    logger.debug("mimetype response = %s" % mime)
    image_data = open(path_filename, 'rb').read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, mimetype=mime)
```

by the way, if i get this working i need another decorator to pass some other tests....
but i first need to get this thing working....

for now it's not a secured url.... plain http.

in java i tried a lot of things... using apache's httpclient 4.2.1
proxy, cookies, authentication negociation, with follow redirects... and so on...

Am I overlooking some basic thing here?...
it seems the login of the website client is not suitable for automated login...

so the problem can be in my code in django....or in the java code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was, using HTTP authorization.
Which is not by default used in the login_required decorator.

adding a custom decorator that checks for HTTP authorization did the trick:

see this example: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/